# Let's get rid of [japanese] & [language] tags

Tags: discussion, tags

Tags [japanese](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/japanese) and [language](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language) on the main site look absolutely useless. Perhaps, we should delete them and add them to blacklist?

Comment: Sorry for using `language` in my question :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [japanese](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/japanese) tag has been blacklisted and removed from the existing questions. I'm not sure about the [lanaguage](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lanaguage) tag, yet. It probably makes sense but, for now, we just removed the one instance to see if it re-asserts itself.

Answer (score 1):

Agree that they don't make that much sense. Not sure how to get rid of them.